# Deriving an ODE of the absolute value from a complex one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

### Problem:

We have given a complex valued ODE of the form:

$\theta'' + (ai+b)~\theta'+ c~\theta = 0$

a,b,c are real constants, such that the solution has a dampened swinging behavior.

### Question:

Can one derive from this a possibly simple real valued ODE for $|\theta|$ or $|\theta|²$?

### Conclusion:

It appears to be not possible, well life is not always simple.
However thanks to all the feedback, you save us a lot of futile attempts and gave us a better understanding of the problem. Maybe we figure out a different way to tackle this problem.

Still we are not sure, how we should handle the correct answer thing in this case, as this question can barely be properly answered.

Comment: Compute the second derivative of $ |θ|^2=θ\bar θ$ by the product rule and insert the equation. What terms remain that can not be recombined into the first derivative of $|θ|^2$?

Comment: This is a fourth order linear system. $\theta = U + i V$ and then you can look at $|\theta|^2 = U^2 + V^2$ if you wish.

Comment: @Gregory As stated in the question, we are interested in formulation in terms of the absolute value, as just solving the system and calculating it numerically is of course trivial. Our intentions regard controlling this system with an expression of the absolute value and the behavior of it matters the most.

Comment: @LutzL see updated question

Comment: Why would you think creating a nonlinear equation from the linear one would make this easier, unless you are just interested in a formulation involving only terms with absolute value. Perhaps I am confused as to what you actually want to do. What is simple real valued ODE?

Comment: We can control the ODE by adding a arbitrary real value to c, and we plan to use $|\theta|²'$ for that.
The reason for this is, that for the case of a real equation this worked really well, and we expected that it would behave in a similar fashion.

It works ok for the complex case, but we thought, that some improvements would be possible if we had a different formulation.

If you are sure that one cannot deduce such a equation, go ahead and post a answer.

By saying "possibly easy", I mean it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to analyze the damping or decay of $|\theta(t)|?$  If so, I have a different suggestion; this will also apply in the real case.  Instead of $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(|\theta|^2)$, let's consider $\frac{d}{dt}(|\theta'|^2)$.  If you multiply your equation by $\overline \theta\,'$ and sum with the product's complex conjugate, the imaginary $ai\theta'$ terms cancel, and you get the ODE (called an energy identity)

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(|\theta'|^2+c|\theta|^2)=-2b|\theta'|^2.
$$
As a first application, you can derive a quick lower bound for the decay rate.  Denote
$$
E(t):=|\theta'(t)|^2+c|\theta(t)|^2. 
$$
If we assume $c>0$, then
$$
E'(t)\ge -2b E(t),
$$
which implies
$$
E(t)\ge e^{-2bt}E(0).
$$
Finding a sharper upper bound than $E(t)\le E(0)$ is more difficult (not for lack of trying!).  This is not surprising, since the decay is different depending on if $b^2>c$ or $b^2<c$ (overdamped versus underdamped oscillator).